# In Elasticsearch,Is there a way to fetch documents that has field more than 2 values

Tags: elasticsearch, fetch-api, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I was looking for query that helps me to fetch all the document that has more than 2 values exactly like this

```
[
  {
    "interactionId": "8d7ec363-8ee1-409d-b80e-17d0c8f9f27d",
    "isRead": true,
    "label": [
      "dd32ec02-3383-4945-a1e8-b1238bdd80ab || Archive",
      "dd32ec02-3383-4945-a1e8-b1238bdd80ab || Archive"
    ],
    "created": 1592637172620
  },
  {
    "interactionId": "117ec363-8ee1-409d-b80e-17d0c8f9f27d",
    "isRead": true,
    "label": [
      "1142ec02-3383-4945-a1e8-b1238bdd80ab || Inbox",
      "dd32ec02-3383-4945-a1e8-b1238bdd80ab || Archive"
    ],
    "created": 1592637172620
  },
   {
    "interactionId": "0d7ec363-8ee1-409d-b80e-17d0c8f9f272",
    "isRead": true,
    "label": [
      "dd32ec02-3383-4945-a1e8-b1238bdd80ab || Archive"
    ],
    "created": 1592637172620
  }
]
```

In the document i am just need to fetch only the documents that has 2 Values in the field **label**

I have tried this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": """doc["label.keyword"].length == 2""",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query fetching me the value if I set the **length == 0** but not fetching any value if  i set the **length == 2** or **length > 1** can any one help what wrong with the above  query and is there any way to fetch the document that has two value.

The mapping for the above document is

```
"mappings": {
      "interaction-4": {
        "properties": {
          "created": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "interactionId": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "isDeleted": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "isRead": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            },
            "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            },
            "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Analyzer and Tokenzier For the Index are

```
 "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1
, "number_of_shards": 2   ,

"analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "search_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
            },
            "index_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "index_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "index_analyzer": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "whitespace",
                "punctuation",
                "symbol"
              ],
              "min_gram": "2",
              "type": "ngram",
              "max_gram": "30"
            }
          }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Is that `nested` datatype? I see array of `interactions`

Comment: no it is not nested documents

Comment: Can you try `doc["label"].length == 2` and I assume that you posted 3 different documents

Comment: Sorry for the confusion it is three different documents . With out keyword it will give me search_phase_execution_exception

Comment: Can you add `mapping` and `sample document from _search`, ES version also?

Comment: Hey I have updated my mapping. Can you please check it

Comment: What is the definition for custom search_analyzer and index_analyzer?

Comment: it is just custom analyzer that have been using for the field.

Comment: When I test the query without those `just custom analyzer`, it works. So I suspect that your custom analyser is causing the problem.

Comment: May be because of that I am not sure. But when i tried for Length == 0 or Length == 1 it is exactly fetching me exact document but it is not working for Length > 1 or Length == 2

Comment: Hi right now changing the mapping type for already index value is not a good idea. Is there any other way to  query the document.

Comment: Unless u provide us the custom analysers, I cannot check.

Comment: Hi i have updated the Custom Analysers in the post Can you please look in to it

Comment: You have max.gram as `30` But recommendation is that `max-gram - min-gram` <= 1. I will look into the actual pblm